# Insert Rowcount to Chart

Tags: php, html, mysql, canvas

how do I this properly? I've been searching for quite awhile now and can't find the exact answer to my question. I can echo the content of $rowcount1 and $rowcount2 just fine and wanted it to use in the chart data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title:{
   text: "LIST RECORD"              
  },
  data: [              
  {
   type: "column",
   dataPoints: [
    { label: "Sold",  y: '$rowcount1'  },        //Properly insert count?
    { label: "Rejected", y: '$rowcount2'  },     //Properly insert count?
   ]
  }
  ]
 });
 chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 60%;"></div>
</body>
</html>

    <?php
error_reporting(0);
// connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "order");
$sql="SELECT * FROM order.item WHERE status IN ('Sold')";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
  $rowcount1=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<?php
error_reporting(0);
// connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "arc");
$sql="SELECT * FROM order.item WHERE status IN ('Rejected')";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
  $rowcount2=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

How do I go about this? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I just have to re-arrange my code. cheers!